# what is the difference between lmFit and rlm

Tags: r

I want to use robust limma on my microarray data and R's user guide says rlm is the correct function to use according to:

http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/limma/html/mrlm.html

I currently have:

```
lmFit(ExpressionMatrix, design, method = "robust", na.omit=T)
```

I can see that I chose the method to be robust. Does that mean that rlm will be called by this lmFit? and if I want it not to be robust, what method should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The help page says:

```
The function mrlm is used if method="robust".
```

And then goes on:

> If method="ls", then gls.series is used if a correlation structure has been specified, i.e., if ndups>1 or block is non-null and correlation is different from zero. If method="ls" and there is no correlation structure, lm.series is used.

Comment: ...and the documentation for `mrlm` in turn says that it calls `rlm`.

Comment: Right. All one needs to do is follow the Yellow (blue on my device) Help Road.

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the links from the help page for `lmFit` (`06.LinearModels`)

> ### Fitting Models
>
> The main function for model fitting is lmFit. This is recommended
>   interface for most users. lmFit produces a fitted model object of
>   class MArrayLM containing coefficients, standard errors and residual
>   standard errors for each gene. lmFit calls one of the following three
>   functions to do the actual computations:
>
> ### `lm.series`
>
> Straightforward least squares fitting of a linear model for
>   each gene.
>
> ### `mrlm`
>
> An alternative to lm.series using robust regression as
>   implemented by the rlm function in the MASS package.
>
> ### `gls.series`
>
> Generalized least squares taking into account correlations
>   between duplicate spots (i.e., replicate spots on the same array) or
>   related arrays. The function duplicateCorrelation is used to estimate
>   the inter-duplicate or inter-block correlation before using
>   gls.series.